# traversing through a list using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

So I am new to recursion and I am trying to make a program where you can enter a list and python tests each integer (lets say 9 for example) and sees if the integer following it is doubled. So if I entered a list of 2 4 8 16 32, would return 4, and -5 -10 0 6 12 9 36, would return 2 because -5 followed by -10 is one and 6 followed by 12 is the second. This is the code I have so far. I feel like I am very close. but just a few thing stand in my way. Any help would be great!

```
L = []
def countDouble(L):
    x = input(f'Enter a list of numbers separated by a space: ')
    y = (x.split(' '))
    print(y[1])
    print(y[0])
    count = 0
    
    y[0] += y[0]
    
# unsure of how to multiple y[0] by 2
    if y[0]*2 == y[1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        count += 0
        
#how would I traverse through the rest of the entered list using recursion?
        
    print(count)
    
countDouble(L)
```

Comment: This looks like a 1 dimensional list. There is no need/way to use recursion here

Comment: Recursion is both inefficient and limited in how deeply it can be used in Python. While it's fine to use it with lists for educational purposes, you should never use it in "real" code: use iteration instead. Python is not Scheme or Haskell, and the `list` type is not a linked list: it's a dynamically resizable array.

Comment: Why does the first example return `4`?

Comment: Also, your function `countDouble` is not the function you would want to make recursive, as it *creates* the list you want to iterate/recurse over.

Comment: Your recursive function should take a list and index. It tests the elements at that index and `index+1`. It stops when the index is the end of the list -- that's the base case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want/need to solve it using recursion, the following will do the trick:

```
def count_sequential_doubles(li, count=0):
    return count_sequential_doubles(li[1:], count + int(li[0] * 2 == li[1])) if len(li) > 1 else count
```

Answer (score 0):

Final edit: OP edited his example so my other code didnt apply

Some good questions people are asking, but in the spirit of helping, here's a recursive function that returns the count of all doubles.

```
def get_doubles_count_with_recursion(a_list, count, previous=None):
    while a_list:
        try:
            first = previous if previous else a_list.pop(0)
            next_item = a_list.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            return count
        if next_item / 2 == first:
            count += 1
        return get_doubles_count_with_recursion(a_list, count, next_item)
    return count

a_list = [1, 3, 5, 10, 11, 14, 28, 56, 88, 116, 232, 464, 500]
doubles = get_doubles_count_with_recursion(a_list, 0)
print(doubles == 5)
```

Probably could clean it up a bit, but it's a lot easier to read than the other guy's ;)

Comment: Or you could assume that the 14 is a typo and should be 16.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this recursive way:

```
def countDouble(L):
    count = 0
    if len(L) == 1:
        return count
    else:
        if int(L[0])*2 == int(L[1]):
            count += 1
        return count + countDouble(L[1:])

x = input(f'Enter a list of numbers separated by a space: ')
y = (x.split(' '))

count = countDouble(y)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to read the entire answer, but in case you are not interested in tips, notes and the process of finding the solution, here are two solutions:

**solution using recursion (not recommended):**

```py
x = input()
y = x.split(' ')
count = 0
def countDouble(i):
    if(i+1 == len(y)):
        return 'recursion ends here when'
    if(int(y[i])*2==int(y[i+1])):
        count += 1
    countDouble(i+1)
countDouble(0)
print(count)
```

this solution just imitates a while loop:

**solution using a while loop (recommended):**

```py
x = input()
y = x.split(' ')
count = 0
i = 0
while(i < len(y) - 1):
    if(int(y[i]) * 2 == int(y[i+1])):
        count += 1
    i += 1
print(count)
```

Before I continue, **here are a few tips and notes:** (some of them will only make sense after)

- I assume the 14 in your example is a typo
- I didn't put the code in a function because it's not needed, but you can change it easily.
- In your code, you are passing L as a parameter to the countDouble() function, but you don't use it. if you don't need a parameter don't pass it.
- when splitting the input, the values of the list are still strings. so you have to invert them to integers (for instance, you can do that with the int() 'function') before comparing their values - otherwise multiplying by 2 will just repeat the string. for example: '13'*2 is the string '1313'
- I don't know why you why you added y[0] to itself in line 9, but based on the code that comes after this would yield incorrect results, you don't need to change the elements in order to get their value multiplied by 2.
- notice that in the else block, nothing has changed. adding 0 to the count doesn't change it. so you can remove the else block entirely

While it's possible to solve the problem in recursion, there's something else designed for these kind of problems: loops.
The problem is essentially repeating a simple check for every element of a list.

**This is how I would arrive to a solution**

so we want to run the following 'code':

```py
if(y[0]*2 == y[1]):
    count += 1
if(y[1]*2 == y[2]):
    count += 1
if(y[2]*2 == y[3]):
    count += 1
...
```

of course the computer doesn't understand what "..." means, but it gives us an idea to the pattern in the code. now we can do the following:

1. divide the extended 'code' into similar sections.
2. identify the variables in the pattern - the values that change between sections
3. find the starting values of all variables
4. find a pattern in the changes of each variable
5. find a breaking point, a condition on one of the variables that tells us we have reached the last repeating section.

here are the steps in this specific problem:

1. the sections are the if statements
2. the variables are the indexes of the elements in y we compare
3. the first index starts at 0 and the second at 1
4. both indexes increase by one after each if-statement
5. when the second index is bigger then the last index of y then we already checked all the elements and we can stop

so all is left is to set the needed variables, have a while loop with the breaking condition we found, and in the while loop have the general case of the repeating sections and then the changing of the variables.
so:

```py
x = input(f'Enter a list of numbers separated by a space: ')
y = (x.split(' '))
count = 0
# setting the starting values of the variables
index1 = 0
index2 = 1
# creating a loop with the breaking condition
while(index2 < len(y)):
    # the general case of the repeated code:
    if(int(y[index1]) * 2 == int(y[index2])):
        count += 1
    # changing the variables for the next loop
    index1 += 1
    index2 += 1
print(count)
```

We see that the index2 is just index1 + 1 at all time. so we can replace it like that:

```py
x = input(f'Enter a list of numbers separated by a space: ')
y = (x.split(' '))
count = 0
index1 = 0
while(index1 + 1 < len(y)):
    if(int(y[index1]) * 2 == int(y[index1 + 1])):
        count += 1
    index1 += 1
print(count)
```

Note: You can use a for loop similarly to the while loop

So in summary, you can use recursion to solve the problem, but the recursion would just be imitating the process of a loop:
in each call, the breaking condition will be checked, the repeated code would run and the variables/parameters would change.
Hope you find this answer useful :)

Answer (score -1):

If I'm reading your question right, you want a count of all pairs where the 2nd item is double the first. (and the `14` in the first list is a typo). In which case a simple function like this should do the job:

```
#a = [2,4,8,16,32]
a = [-5, -10, 0, 16, 32]

count = 0
for i, x in enumerate(a):
  # Stop before the list overflows
  if i < len(a) - 1:
    # If the next element is double the current one, increment the counter
    if a[i+1] == x * 2:
      count = count + 1
  else:
    break

print(count)
```

Comment: Not recursion, OP is specifically asking about using recursion